# Getting correct encoding from php cURL

Tags: javascript, php, encoding, character-encoding, php-curl

(see update at bottom of post)

Using the Chrome network logger, I notice a given XHR request:

**Request Headers**

```
GET ... HTTP/1.1
Host: ...
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36
Origin: ...
Authorization: Jra45648WwbbQ
Accept: */*
Referer: ...
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

**Response Headers**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Referer, User-Agent, deportes
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ...
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Authorization, x-request-id, x-mlbam-reply-after
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Date: Sun, 16 Apr 2017 ... GMT
Server: nginx/1.11.3
Vary: Accept
X-Request-ID: ...
Content-Length: 16
Connection: keep-alive
```

The response content  is `@  EqV¡^MSÁ9`

Perfect. This is the correct output.

Now, I need to recreate this exact exchange within PHP using cURL. So I duplicate the request using the same headers.

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'gzip',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
    ));
```

However, the output here is `@  EqV–¡^MSƒÁ’9`, which is clearly different.

I need to get it in the original format (`@  EqV¡^MSÁ9`), because eventually the output from the PHP will be served to a javascript script, and the value of `charCodeAt` has different results between these two output. I'm not sure how to approach this problem.

[image: Example of the two different outputs in Notepad++]

As you can see, after the XHR request, the response preview in Chrome is correct:

[image: Chrome Network Logger Preview]

If I change the encoding type of my PHP page's output to **Western (ISO-8859-15)**, I get `@    EqV¡^MSÁ9`.

And if I paste that output into Notepad++, I get something **very, very** similar to what I want, but still slightly different (in this case, different by one single character). So maybe this is very close to the encoding I need?

[image: Encoding]

How can I find the encoding I need? What is the default encoding of chrome, since it seems to handle the response just fine?

**UPDATE:** I tested with a new value, `òÝD¶0v¢ÔL·ßÎO   Ó`, and using `mb_convert_encoding($r, 'utf-8', 'ISO-8859-15')` gave me the correct result. So why is it encoding that particular response (`@   EqV¡^MSÁ9`) gives me a value that is short a character?

Comment: Can you share the `url` on which you are submitting request?

Comment: Do you know what encoding is used for the response?

Comment: @TurtleTread  I update the post with the response headers, but I don't think that really provides any info other than maybe the `Content-Type`. I'm not aware of any encoding, because as you can see in my second picture, the Chrome preview of the response looks fine. This would be the data as it is directly served because it's just the response preview.

Comment: What's on the response tab?

Comment: @TurtleTread The response and preview tabs are identical

Comment: Can you try change your browser encoding to utf-8 OR some other encodings? Why the response text so strange?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome default encoding is **UTF-8**, and if you set it to to UTF-8 
 `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');`  your text will be as expected you can try that [here](http://string-functions.com/encodedecode.aspx).
Also detecting the encoding is painful since it can encounter many issues using `mb_detect_encoding` but in this case it can be helpful if you specify the expected order of detection like so:

```
mb_detect_encoding($val, 'UTF-8,ISO-8859-15');
```

In my personal experience it is worthless without specifying the targets and in the right order, for example you need to list `UTF-8` before `ISO-8859-1` in your encoding_list or it will return `ISO-8859-1` in most cases 

**UPDATE**:
The [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt-array.php) says `CURLOPT_ENCODING => ''` handle all encodings you can try that but as I said since you are dealing with a known encoding wich is `UTF-8` please try

```
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'UTF-8',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
    ));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Using what you provided, it says the encoding is ISO-8859-15. When I go to convert, I get something very, very close, but still off by one character (see last picture in my original post). Any idea why this is? Is it still simply just the wrong encoding or is there something else at play?

Comment: Answer Updated. If you try  the string in [here](http://example.com) with setting Encode/Encode to UTF-8 with `@   EqV¡^MSÁ9` you will get the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You can attempt to detect the encoding of the octet stream and then convert it to a known charset.

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo mb_detect_encoding($result);
$resultUTF8 = mb_convert_encoding($result, 'ISO-8859-15', 'utf-8');
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! The result of `mb_detect_encoding($result, 'UTF-8,ISO-8859-15');` is `ISO-8859-15`. But if you refer to my last picture in my main post, the result is very very close but off by a single character. Would you have any idea why that is?

Comment: Charcode 32 in the original output is a space in ISO 8859-15. Fortunately you have identified the correct encoding. Have you set the character encoding and EOL conversion to Unix in your text editor before pasting the result?